# Twilio salesforce integration error while sending SMS more than 160 char

Tags: apex, api, rest, twilio

I am trying to send SMS from Salesforce using Twilio's REST API. I keep getting below response.

```
{
    "code": 21605,
    "message": "The message body exceeds the 160 character limit.",
    "more_info": "https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/21605",
    "status": 400
}
```

I am not getting any error when I send sms using Twilio console. So is it salesforce restricting me to send more then 160 char?

My sample request is:

```
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setEndpoint('https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/'+accountSid+'/SMS/Messages.json');
req.setMethod('POST');
req.setHeader('Authorization','Basic '+EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Blob.valueOf(accountSid+':' +token)));
req.setBody('To='+EncodingUtil.urlEncode(phoneNumber,'UTF-8')+'&From='+EncodingUtil.urlEncode(fromPhNumber,'UTF-8')+'&Body='+mapOfPhoneNumberAndMessage.get(phoneNumber));
Http http = new Http();
HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);
System.debug('=============SMS Body========='+res.getBody());
```

FYI -  I can send SMS when message length is less then 160 char.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Salesforce isn't restricting the character limit. Try sending to '/Messages' instead of '/SMS/Messages'. This should allow up to 1600 characters.

https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/messaging/message